# Google Adsense loads scripts multiple times

Tags: javascript, adsense, google-ads-api

I have a page that displays Google Ads - three of them. The ads are initialized as follows:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

<ins class="adsbygoogle class-resp" style="display:inline-block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-4283524395367264" data-ad-slot="8923673879"></ins>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>

<ins class="adsbygoogle class-resp" style="display:inline-block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-4283524395367264" data-ad-slot="8923673879"></ins>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>

<ins class="adsbygoogle class-resp" style="display:inline-block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-4283524395367264" data-ad-slot="8923673879"></ins>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

The problem is that the page size is ridiculously large and the reason is primarily that each ad seems to require its own download of each of the following scripts i.e. each of these is downloaded three times, adding around 700kb to each page load (which for mobile browsing is too big)

http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20150402/r20150224/show_ads_impl.js
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20150402/r20150224/expansion_embed.js
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20150402/r20110914/abg.js

Does anyone know of a way to force the three ads to share a single download of each of the three scripts above or does each advert HAVE to download its own copy of each of them??

Answer (score -2):

Once a script is downloaded it is cached (If cache headers are available), for the second request of the script is loaded from cache, So it does not waste any bandwidth or does not send any request to domain/host.

I just checked http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20150402/r20150224/show_ads_impl.js

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK =>
P3P => policyref="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/p3p.xml", CP="NOI DEV PSA PSD IVA IVD OTP OUR OTR IND OTC"
Timing-Allow-Origin => *
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy => cross-origin
Vary => Accept-Encoding
Date => Sat, 04 Sep 2021 06:08:13 GMT
Expires => Sat, 04 Sep 2021 06:08:13 GMT
Cache-Control => private, max-age=1209600
Content-Type => text/javascript; charset=ISO-8859-1
X-Content-Type-Options => nosniff
Content-Disposition => attachment; filename="f.txt"
Server => cafe
X-XSS-Protection => 0
Accept-Ranges => none
```

It has cache control header.